# Mass re-write rule that keeps the existing URL structure and only rewrites the end of the URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently working on a plumbing website which has both **multi lingual** and **multi regional** content, below are some examples of the current URL structure...

http://www.domain.com/product/de/?region=uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de/?region=uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de/?region=uk

For SEO purposes i'm looking to rewrite the end of these URLs to be...

http://www.domain.com/product/de-uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de-uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de-uk

I would also settle for...

http://www.domain.com/product/de/uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de/uk

http://www.domain.com/product/plumbing-and-heating/de/uk

I know I could do something like...

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)region=uk($|&)
RewriteRule ^product/de/$ /product/de-uk/? [L,R=301]`

which would rewrite...

http://www.domain.com/product/de/?region=uk to be http://www.domain.com/product/de-uk/

However as there are obviously a lot of different languages, regions and subdirectories to do these one by one would be a massive task as their are many different combinations!

Therefore i'm looking for an easier more manageable solution, any help appreciated?

Comment: Is it always the same URL structure`http://example.com/subdirectory/language/?region=something`? exactly one subdirectory?

Comment: Are region and language always exactly two letters?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)$ /$1/$2/$3/?region=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)$ /$1/$2/?region=$3 [NC,L]
```